# Get Status of SharePoint workflows in the SP farm using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I am trying to figure out it what properties of $list or $wp return the status of workflow(Completed, In progress, Error Occurred and canceled). or how i can get the status of each workflow in the SP Farm. I managed to get Url, List name and etc. except workflow status.

## $siteurl = Get-SPWebApplication https:// | Get-SPSite -Limit ALL

$siteurl="xxx"

function Get-Workflows($siteurl)
{

$site=Get-SPSite -Limit ALL
$WorkflowDeatils=@()

foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
foreach($list in $web.Lists)
{
foreach($wf in $list.WorkflowAssociations)
{
if ($wf.Name -notlike "*Previous Version*")
{
$row=new-object PSObject
add-Member -inputObject $row -memberType NoteProperty -name "Site URL" -Value $web.Url
add-Member -inputObject $row -memberType NoteProperty -name "List Title" -Value $list.Title
add-Member -inputObject $row -memberType NoteProperty -name "RootFolder" -Value $list.RootFolder
add-Member -inputObject $row -memberType NoteProperty -name "Workflow name" -Value $wf.Name

## Status of workflow ?

$WorkflowDeatils+=$row
}
}
}
}
$WorkflowDeatils
}

Get-Workflows | Export-csv C:\workflow.txt
$site.Dispose();

Answer (score 0):

To get workflow status, we can use the PowerShell script like below.

```
$siteURL = "http://sp2013/sites/team"
$site = Get-SPSite($siteURL)
foreach($web in $site.AllWebs){
    $wfm=New-objectMicrosoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($web)
    foreach($spList in $web.Lists){     
        $workflowInstanceService=$wfm.GetWorkflowInstanceService()
        foreach($item in $spList.Items){
            $workflowInstances=$workflowInstanceService.EnumerateInstancesForListItem($spList.ID,$item.ID)
            foreach($wf in $workflowInstances) {
                write -host "workflow Status:" $wf.Status
            }                   
        }
    }
    $web.Dispose()
}
```

Refer to: [SharePoint 2013 Workflow: Programmatically Access Workflow Properties](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-workflow.html)

Or we can use the PowerShell with CSOM code to achieve it. Check the solution with source PowerShell script below.

[How get the workflow execution status for all the workflows in a SharePoint Site](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-get-the-workflow-7d00eed9)